# how to save the return of an api in a variable in httparty and ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, visual-studio, rubygems, httparty

I'm sending a POST request in an API that returns a token, how do I assign a variable to this generated value?

Comment: `[@|@@|$]variable_name = value`.

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby, you assign a variable using the equal sign `=` binary infix assignment operator. See section 11.4.2.2.2 *Single variable assignments* of the [ISO/IEC 30170:2012 *Information technology — Programming languages — Ruby* specification](https://iso.org/standard/59579.html).

For example, to assign the result of sending the message `bar` to the local variable `foo`, you would write:

```ruby
foo = bar
```